# htaccess rewrite for everything after the extension that is not a query string

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to rewrite URLs in such a way as to remove everything after the extension (in my case .php) that is not a query string.

Ideally, I'd like these requests to respond with a 404, but it seems the default Apache/PHP setup is to simply return the page as normal.

For example a request to `/index.php/anystring` shows my home page, not a 404 as I would expect.

Wanted to reach out as I'd be surprised if someone hasn't solved this problem already.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to disable the pathname info using AcceptPathInfo Directive,

Add the following line to your htaccess :

```
AcceptPathInfo off
```

Comment: Wow, I had no idea that directive existed. Thanks!